# Why Does My Baked Texture Have Dark Spots?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I baked a skin texture for my model using Cycles Render Engine, however the fingers are a darker color.
[image]

This is the setup:
[image]

This is what it looks like not being baked:
[image]

Why is this happening? It only happens to the fingers; the rest of the body is the correct color.

Thank you!

Comment: hello, hard to say, maybe share your file so that we can try a bake: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Are there any hidden objects (in the viewport) that are still rendered and could cast this shadow on the hand?

Comment: @Blunder, there are no hidden objects. The only thing enabled in renders is the body that I'm trying to bake.